# Importing "regular" javascript packages installed with npm in Webpack

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack, require

I've npm installed [smooth-scroll](https://github.com/cferdinandi/smooth-scroll), a package which does not support the **import** syntax.

I am sure it will work If I manually copy the source code to the libs library and use a **script** tag:

```
<script src="/libs/smooth-scroll.js"></script>
```

But how do I use the **import** syntax with it. I've tried two options and neither worked.

**option A:**

```
import scroller from 'smooth-scroll';
```

**option B:**

```
import {scroller} from 'smooth-scroll';
```

It was a guess and obviously not meant to work but how does one uses **import** and get Webpack to serve it?

**UPDATE:**

I've noticed that the package's source starts with the following line:

```
(function (root, factory) {
    if ( typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ) {
        define([], factory(root));
    } else if ( typeof exports === 'object' ) {
        module.exports = factory(root);
    } else {
        root.smoothScroll = factory(root);
    }
})(typeof global !== 'undefined' ? global : this.window || this.global, (function (root) {
...
```

Does this means the package already supports ES2015 import?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest answer would be to go into the source code of smooth-scroll.js and to add to the bottom:

```
export default smoothScrollFunction;
```

Where smoothScrollFunction is the function / object / whatever that you're wanting to import. Then the import statement would work in other code using:

```
import scroller from "./lib/smooth-scroller";
```

That's how importing and exporting works with ES2015. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

Comment: That's good to know. However this means "npm install" won't work when I setup the project on a fresh computer. Voting up though! thanks

Comment: You can make an install script that puts the export line at the end of the file and put it into `scripts` in package.json so you can use `npm run whatever` (whatever being the name you give the script in `scripts`), either that or send in a pull request to the maintainer of smooth-scroll to add support for ES2015 import/export support.